# Angular re-calc directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anybody help me with next question:

I have next HTML code

```
<button class="btn btn-link" type="submit" popover-bind="{{value['id']}}">Description</button>
```

**popover-bind** - is my directive

```
mytestApp.directive("popoverBind",function()
    {
    return {
        link:function(scope,element, attrs)
            {
            var opts = 
                {
                placement:"right",
                title:scope.get_title_for_popover(attrs['popoverBind']),
                content:scope.get_descr_for_popover(attrs['popoverBind']),
                html:true
                }
            $(element).popover(opts);
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see - **content** and **title** are determining as function results, so It depends on function calculation. But directive saving it is first result value all time, and even when scope is changed.

Any ideas probably how to re-render HTML page or re-bind directive???

Thanks!

Comment: try this attrs.$observe('popoverBinf', function (value) {
                      var opts = 
                {
                placement:"right",
                title:scope.get_title_for_popover(attrs['popoverBind']),
                content:scope.get_descr_for_popover(attrs['popoverBind']),
                html:true
                }
            $(element).popover(opts);
            }
                  });

Comment: observe attribute and on attribute change rebind popover

Comment: try to put `$scope.$watch()`